# Am I Hispanic or Caucasian?

Tags: family-tree, naming-convention

My father was born in Spain and all his family are Spanish from as many generations back as we can find, my mother was born in Ireland and her Irish family history has been traced back to the times of vikings. I was born in New Zealand, and am unsure what my correct 'race' is. I always mark myself down as Caucasian but could it be that I am part Hispanic too?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  This is a similar question asked a while ago that you may want to review: http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/2070/how-do-you-determine-how-much-of-an-ethnicity-you-are-according-to-your-ancestry/3562#3562

Comment: I'm curious about where you need to write down your "race" because your question sounds more like it is related to the US Census Bureau designations described at [Wikipedia's Hispanic page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hispanic) than something in New Zealand.  That page seems to say that most Hispanics are considered Caucasians.  In any event, I think it is more interesting to think about where our ancestors lived rather than trying to classify by "race".  I think you are "half Spanish, half Irish".

Comment: We would certainly welcome questions from you about your ancestors from [tag:spain] and/or [tag:ireland].

Comment: Spaniards **are** Caucasian.